# Numpy: fast/easy way to get indices of array whose value is equal to another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an array of integers `x` and I want to do the following:

1. get an array `unique_x` of the unique values of `x`
2. build an array `y` in which `y[i]` is the index in `unique_x` of the value `x[i]`.

I managed to do this as follows:

```
import numpy as np

unique_x = np.unique(x)
y = np.zeros_like(x)
for k, value in unique_x:
   indices, = np.nonzero(x == value)
   y[indices] = k
```

My question is: is there a way to do this using only numpy builtin functions and some slicing? I have a feeling that this loop won't be as fast as it could be if this was done with numpy builtins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `np.unique()` does what you want it to (returns only the first occurence of each element; it doesn't return only those elements which occur once), you can do use the `return_index` argument:

```
In [1]: x = array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1])
In [2]: unique_x, unique_indexes = np.unique(x, return_index=True)
In [3]: unique_x
Out[3]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
In [4]: unique_indexes
Out[4]: array([0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7])
```

(`x` does not need to be sorted, but `unique_x` will be). If you want the indicies necessary to reconstruct `x` from `unique_x`, on the other hand, you can use the `return_inverse` argument, as pointed out by @xtofl:

```
In [5]: unique_x, unique_inverse = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
In [6]: unique_inverse
Out[6]: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 0])
```

Comment: does `x` have to be sorted for this to work?  (would it work with e.g. `[1, 2, 1]`)

Comment: ... I believe what OP wants is `return_inverse=True`.

Comment: I've edited my answer with some more information for the OP - thanks.